# Non-Secure Video on https page

Tags: security, https

Okay, so I have created a webpage for a client who is using https protocol, but wants to stream video from a non-secured source (not YouTube, unfortunately). Best case scenario: I'd be looking for a way to stream the video without getting security warnings for mixed content (especially a problem in any IE). I realize this may be impossible, so my secondary question would be how to put some sort of placeholder into the page if the user decides not to view the non-secure content. This way my layout is not totally butchered. Obviously though, it would be best not to trip any security issues. The video we are trying to stream is accessed via the below code (given by client for embedding), if that helps anything. Any help is appreciated!

```
<script src="http://video.bigthink.com/player.js?height=183&autoplay=0&width=325&deepLinkEmbedCode=Y5M3U4MTq4-WJs8Wn0bLOXi0AeGcxHf4&embedCode=Y5M3U4MTq4-WJs8Wn0bLOXi0AeGcxHf4"></script>
```

Comment: Also, I find it strange that we are embedding banner ads from this url with the code they give, and those are NOT setting off a mixed content warning....why is this? http://earthhour.wwf.org.uk/get_involved/take_part/resources22/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

Usually you just have to change the src from http to https, unfortunately these video sites are not thinking about secuirty and refuse to pay $30 for a certificate.   I think your best bet it to make that specific page non-https or use an iframe.

Comment: That would be nice if I could say that, unfortunately the client is adamant in using https

Comment: Yeah,  https is great.  So, you'll have to use an iframe.

Comment: iframe are dangerous

Comment: @Begueradj As long as you have clickjacking mitigation - then an iframe is just fine.